# How can I add to a multiplier inside an inner for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects, increment

I have an array of objects, and each object has a nested object with a key that I would like to increment each iteration with a higher multiplier.

I have an  object:

```
object = {
    id: 1,
    innerArr: [
        {
            key: 50
        },
        {
            key: 20
        }
    ]
}
```

then I want to:

Push it to a new array, X times.

multiply the 'key' with growing increments in each iteration

```
const arr = [];
let increment = 0.85;

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    const { id } = object;

    object.innerArr.forEach(obj => {
        obj.key *= increment;
    })

    arr.push({
        id,
        innerArr
    })
    increment += 0.05;    // (1:) 0.9, (2:) 0.95...
}
```

The resulting array should look something like this:

```
arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        innerArr: [
            {
                key: 42.5
            },
            {
                key: 17
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        innerArr: [
            {
                key: 45
            },
            {
                key: 18
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        innerArr: [
            {
                key: 47.5
            },
            {
                key: 19
            }
        ]
    } // and the rest...
]
```

But, for some (probably obvious) reason, when I do something similar, all the keys get the last increment only (the 7th iteration of increment += 0.05).

How can I get the desired output? and, what mechanism am I missing that cause this behavior.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the `for`-loop, what is the value of the variable `innerArr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! when I copied the innerArr, I did not actually copy its objects but referenced them, so the final arr contains only references to the **initial** object. So incrementing obj.key affects the initial innerArr object.

The solution is to:

1. deep copy the innerArr
2. make changes on the copy
3. push the copy to arr
4. start over

```
const arr = [];
let increment = 0.85;

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    const { id } = object;
    let newInnerArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(innerArr));

    object.newInnerArr.forEach(obj => {
        obj.key *= increment;
    })

    arr.push({
        id,
        newInnerArr
    })
    increment += 0.05;    // (1:) 0.9, (2:) 0.95...
}
```

Hope it helps someone :)